# inet_addr return network order integer addr?

Tags: c, sockets

i run the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main () {
    unsigned long conv_addr;
    char *addr2 = "127.0.0.1";
    conv_addr = inet_addr(addr2);
    printf("Network ordered interger addr : %#lx \n", conv_addr);
}
```

output

```
Network ordered interger addr : 0x100007f
```

But the nework ordered is Big-Endian, i think the output should be

```
Network ordered interger addr : 0x7f000001
```

Why is `0x100007f`?

Comment: I'd say that looks about right... The order is reversed if printed on a little-endian system.

Comment: You need to check the content of each byte in memory. That way you can avoid any endianess issues during printing etc.

Comment: @Gerhardh i don't know how to check...

Comment: You can view it in debugger or use `unsigned char *buf=(unsigned char*)&conv_addr; printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);` to check.

Comment: @Gerhardh I see. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The representation *in memory* is `0x7f 0x00 0x00 0x01`

When converted into a `long` on a little endian system that comes out as `0x0100007f`.